# Incrementing a foreach loop and only showing one child

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach

I'm creating a custom Google map that plots multiple markers.

### ***View the link as it will make it easier to explain what is happening and what I want***

If you click on each marker it shows company names that are grabbed from the child pages. At the moment it's showing ALL the company names on each marker. How can I show just one company name per marker? i.e So one say "MediWales" and the other says "Teamworks Design & Marketing", and so on when I add more companies.

Here's the code controlling the little popup:

```
<?php $pages = get_pages(array('child_of' => 1873, 'sort_column' => 'menu_order')); 
$counter = 1;
foreach($pages as $post) 
{
setup_postdata($post); 
$fields = get_fields(); ?> 
<p><?php $counter++; echo $fields->company_name;?></p>
<?php } wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Once it's looped through once, the next time it loops through I need it to start on the next child and not show the first one.

**UPDATE:
It seems like it's very close, it's showing one company but the same one on both markers.**

```
<?php 
$counter = 1; 
$pages = get_pages(array('child_of' => 1873, 'sort_column' => 'menu_order', 'offset' => $counter, 'number' => 1)); 
foreach($pages as $post) { 
setup_postdata($post); 
$fields = get_fields(); ?> 
<p><?php echo $fields->company_name; echo $counter; ?></p>
<?php $counter++; } 
wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: Is it possible to use the "offset" parameter somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is the fact that `PHP` is by nature preprocessed. `JavaScript` doesn't run that `PHP` everytime you click that marker.

Your best bet is to output a `JSON` object from `PHP` containing all the markers and their attributes, then parse it dynamically with `JavaScript`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, as it's PHP does it not matter what the Javascript is doing. The php is grabbing data from my CMS. The problem is with the php loop rather than anything javascript.

Comment: Thanks for the update although I have no idea how to do that! I can't even get the php loop to work outside of all the Javascript. I'm also not convinced by the preprocessed comment as someone also said the same yet it's processing some other php within the javascript just fine. For instance the post codes of the plotted markers are from my CMS via php.

Comment: Perhaps ignore the javascript and try to get the php snippet working on a normal page.

Comment: You said that the loop returns every company name right? That means it's working. You just need to restructure your PHP so that it outputs all of your information at one time for JavaScript to handle, otherwise put the PHP in another page and make an Ajax call.

Comment: I can't get the php to work the way I want it on a normal page - that's the problem.